# Userform Data entry "Update" setting wrong values when editing an entry

Tags: excel, vba, userform, data-entry

So I've got a userform for entering and looking up customer information, Everythign seems to currently work, except for the "Update" Button. When utilizing the update button, its changing my city and state values to my zipcode value, aswell as adjusting whatever else was changed. City and state should not be changing to my zipcode value. city and state values are populated utilizing a vlookup within a zipcodedata tab.

Below is the code for my update button:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()

If Me.CustID.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Select customer record to update!"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database")
Dim Selected_Row As Long
Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.CustID.Value), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Database").Range("A:A"), 0)
'Validations-----------------------------------------------------
If Me.CustomerName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Plese enter the customers name!", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
'-------
If Me.CustomerBusiness.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Plese enter the customers business!", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
'-------
If Me.CustomerAddress.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Plese enter the customers address!", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
'-------
If Me.CustomerPhone.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Plese enter the customers phone number!", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
'----------------------------------------------------------------
sh.Range("B" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerName.Value
sh.Range("C" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerBusiness.Value
sh.Range("D" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerAddress.Value
sh.Range("E" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.City.Value
sh.Range("F" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.State.Value
sh.Range("G" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.Zipcode.Value
sh.Range("H" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerPhone.Value
sh.Range("I" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerEmail.Value
sh.Range("J" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.MachineSerial1.Value
sh.Range("K" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.MachineSerial2.Value
sh.Range("L" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.MachineSerial3.Value

'----------------------------------------------------------------
Me.CustomerName.Value = ""
Me.LCaseName.Value = ""
Me.CustomerBusiness.Value = ""
Me.CustomerAddress.Value = ""
Me.Zipcode.Value = ""
Me.City.Value = ""
Me.State.Value = ""
Me.CustomerPhone.Value = ""
Me.CustomerEmail.Value = ""
Me.MachineSerial1.Value = ""
Me.MachineSerial2.Value = ""
Me.MachineSerial3.Value = ""
Me.CustID.Value = ""
'----------------------------------------------------------------
Call Refresh
End Sub
```

Here is the code for populating the City and State text boxes:

```
Private Sub Zipcode_Change()
Dim rng As Range
Dim a As Integer

On Error Resume Next
a = 0
Set rng = Worksheets("ZipCodeData").Range("ZipCodes")
Lastrow = Worksheets("ZipCodeData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Me.Zipcode = Worksheets("ZipCodeData").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
a = a + 1
End If
Next
If a >= 1 Then
Me.City.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Zipcode.Value, rng, 2, 0)
Me.State.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Zipcode.Value, rng, 3, 0)
End If
If a = 0 Then
Me.City.Value = ""
Me.State.Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```

I've tried commenting out my "Zipcode_Change" sub, as I thought perhaps it was having issues interpreting the vlookup values when utilizing the update feature. I have a "add" button (which is identical to the update button, except the Selected_Row is a Last_Row. The "Add" button functions and works as intended, so I recopied my "Add" button code and readjusted it for the update button, and the issue persists.

Comment: `Worksheets("ZipCodeData").Range("ZipCodes")` includes what actual range?  Not that `VLookUp()` is inherently bad, but I personally find it more useful to use `Index(,Match())` as I can specify the look-up range and the output range more directly, or even use `Find()` to get the appropriate header to define a `.Column`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, it may behoove you to use indentations and `with` statements to make your code A) more readable, and B) less redundancy.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` in your `Zipcode_Change()` code, where you may not be finding a `vlookup` output value and it's instead outputting the lookup value... that's what i was getting at in my first comment.

Comment: @cyril - I'll agree my formatting is atrocious, I'll work on indenting and improving that moving forward. I went with vlookup as the zipcode data fit the requirements and was quick and easy for me to setup.  Removing the on error resume next unfortunately did not correct the issue.

Comment: @cyril, the zipcodecodes range is =ZipCodeData!$a$1:$c$44016

Comment: `Me.Zipcode.Value` may have an impact... doesn't hurt to qualify.

Comment: Rather than looping to find a matching zipcode value, you can can the error either with `iserror` or using `countif()` in your if-statement; would save a bit of time referring to a sheet and looping/reading cell by cell.

Comment: Just curious ..... You wrote : _Everythign seems to currently work_. Me:  so, before clicking the Update button, the city and state textbox already show a correct lookup value based on what user type in zipcode textbox ? You wrote : _When utilizing the update button, its changing my city and state values to my zipcode value_ Me : did you mean that when you step run the UpdateButton_Click() code, you see the value in the city textbox and the state textbox change to a value seen in zipcode textbox ? Example : (continue)

Comment: while filling the form, after you finish typing in the zipcode textbox, the city and state textboxes are automatically filled with a correct city name (say "aaa") and state name (say "bbb"). Meaning the Zipcode_Change() sub runs correctly. Next you are ready to fill the sheet's cell with the information in the form, so you click the Update button by step run into the code.... but somewhere in the code line when the yellow pass it, you see the city and state textbox value is changing from "aaa" / "bbb" to the zipcode textbox value you've typed before. Please CMIWW.

Comment: @karma, correct, the UpdateButton_Click seems to be bugged, but all of my other functions in this form operate as expected. The zipcode change sub does indeed run 100 as expected. When a legitimate zipcode is put in the zipcode box, the city and state populate as expected with the right info. When clicking the update button, it seems to be changing the city and state values in the Customer Database to my zipcode value.

Comment: Have you tried to step run the update button code to know how did it happen ? I mean, right before you hit F8 to have the yellow pass this `sh.Range("E" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.City.Value` line ... do you still see the city textbox still has a correct value (say "aaa") ? (If not, then somewhere in the sub there is a line which causing the city textbox value change). If yes, then after you hit again F8 making the yellow pass that line, do you see cell E row-N value now fill with "aaa" which is the city textbox value ? or fill with other than "aaa" which is the zipcode textbox value ?

Comment: @karma so, went to step through the code, and now the UpdateButton_Click () isn't updating anything. When stepping through, and getting to sh.Range("B" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CustomerName.Value, it acts as if the sub ends and it jumps up to the sub at the top of the userform panel (being a list item double click event). Not sure what's going on at this point. Reverted the changes mentioned above, thinking I fubared somewhere. Truly scratching my head right now

Comment: @TylerWilson, that's strange.  Is the `Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.CustID.Value), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer Database").Range("A:A"), 0)` gives you a correct/expected row number ?

Comment: @karma - inspecting the selected row in the locals window shows its calculating the correct row number per selected row.

Comment: @TylerWilson, I am sorry I give up, as I don't know why is that. If I were you, I will remove the whole code for UpdateButton_Click sub, then write a very simple one : for example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database").Range("B5").select`. If it select a correct cell, then I add `selection.value = CustomerName.Value`.  If it fills a corect value, then I change those two lines into one line : `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database").Range("B5").value = CustomerName.Value`. continue

Comment: If it's correct, then I make `LR = 5` and change that one line into  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database").Range("B" & LR).value = CustomerName.Value`. If it's correct then I add `set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customer Database")` and change that line into `sh.Range("B" & LR).value = CustomerName.Value`. Something like that :)